# How do I enable right click on a Lenovo Z580?

Tags: touchpad, lenovo, ideapad

Right click doesn't work with Ubuntu 12.04 on a Lenovo Z580. One can work around this using a two-finger click, but its pretty annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer was taken from the following more generic post. Note that I also put this answer up on the Lenovo forum.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingTouchpadDetection

And go to the section: *Enabling right button click for clickpads on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS*

The short protocol as follows:

Download `enable-rightbutton.sh` script:

```
wget 'https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingTouchpadDetection?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=enable-rightbutton.sh'
```

Set executable permission:

```
chmod a+x enable-rightbutton.sh
```

Look up the ID number for the SynPS/2 Synaptics Touchpad:

```
xinput
```

In my case it is 14:

```
./enable-rightbutton.sh 14
```

Note: replace 14 with whatever id number your touchpad had for xinput

Then everything starts working.

Pretty great! Now you only have to deal with the slow start up issue and your lenovo z580 will be as good as functional!